# Django media image full path for PIL

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, python-imaging-library, django-media

i am trying to get the full path of an uploaded django image (to the media folder) to use it with PIL but it returns `FileNotFoundError`

code:

```
from PIL import Images
img_dir = Image.objects.all().first()
img = img_dir.image1.url
im = Image.open(img)
```

how can i solve this error?

Comment: Since `media folder` mentioned, I assume you have some model with `ImageField` or `FileField`. Line 2 has major flaw: it attempts to query PIL Image class which is not about DB at all instead of Django model class with `image1` field.

Comment: Thank you for the comment i did some research and replaced `img_dir.image1.url` with `img_dir.image1.path`

Answer (score 0):

```
scheme = request.scheme
host = request.get_host()
image_url = f"{scheme}://{host}{settings.MEDIA_URL}{image_name}"
```

this may help